# M1.9 set value for custom product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute, custom, custom-attributes

I need to **set a new value** to a **custom product attribute**.

I want this to happen when a new product is created. The default value of the attribute is 0, I need to set it to 1.

I have an event observer for catalog_product_load_after.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero_Observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>schott_showquoteatzero/observer</class>
                        <method>showQuoteButtonAtZeroPrice</method>
                    </Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero_Observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my observer

```
class Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero_Model_Observer
    {
        public function showQuoteButtonAtZeroPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $product->setData('quotemode_conditions',1);
            $product->save();
        }
    }
```

It does not change the attribute value. Can anyone help?

Comment: is your observer file calling?

Comment: yes, is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default value for your attribute in:

> Admin -> Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage attributes

If you want to set the value when you create a product from backend, you can use `catalog_product_new_action` event.

When you use `catalog_product_save_before` event, please remove `$product->save();` otherwise it will create an infinite loop.

---

Btw ... is it possible that your config.xml isn't complete? I miss the `<models>` node:

```
<models>
    <schott_showquoteatzero>
        <class>Schott_ShowQuoteAtZero_Model</class>
    </schott_showquoteatzero>
<models>
```

Comment: In admin it is not possible to edit the attribute (default value)

Comment: catalog_product_new_action  does not change a thing

Comment: config is good, this structure works for other modules too.

Comment: @SelfDiagnostics You're right, admin default value only works for text attributes. Without declared `<models>` it can not work ... Can you please add a `Mage::log` to you observer to ensure it is called?

Comment: sorry, I did not read your text carefully enough. You are right, it works, thank you!